# Total number of perfect square which are factors of n

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

A number $N$ can be factorized as $$N = p_1^5 p_2^4 p_3^7.$$

Find total number of perfect square, which are factors of $N$.

Comment: Hint: if a number is a perfect square, what can you say about the exponents of its prime factors?

Comment: Are $p_1, p_2, p_3$ primes?  Are they distinct?  (It doesn't say anywhere in the question.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a factor to be a square it needs to have an even number of powers of $p_1$, an even number of powers of $p_2$ AND an even number of powers of $p_3$.

So, the even exponents of $p_1$ are 0, 2, 4. The even exponents of $p_2$ are 0, 2, 4. And the even exponents of $p_3$ are 0, 2, 4, and 6.
So, all of the square factors occur when we take combinations of exponents from the three sets. Using the rule of multiplication there are $3\times3\times4=36$ perfect squares.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if a number is a perfect square, it must have the exponents of each prime even. Make sure you see why this is true. For simplicity, let $a$ be the exponent of $p_{1},$ $b$ be the exponent of $p_{2},$ and $c$ be the exponent of $p_{3}.$ Each of these exponents must be even and be less than or equal to $5,$ $4,$ and $7,$ respectively. Using basic constructive counting, there are a total of $3 \times 3 \times 4 = \boxed{36}$ square factors of $N.$

Comment: It remains a mystery why somebody would downvote this.